# Cards and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, computer-science, playing-cards

I am trying to write a code to make a card turn every time I press it.
Is the problem in createGUI in JCardDemo applet? How to correct it then?
here's my code.thx

JCardbutton class
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

```
public class JCardButton extends JButton {
private ImageIcon myFace;
private ImageIcon myBack;
private boolean myFaceUp;
private Rank myRank;
private Suit mySuit;

public Rank getRank() {
    return myRank;
}

public Suit getSuit() {
    return mySuit;
}

public JCardButton(Suit s, Rank r, ImageIcon face, ImageIcon back) {
    super();

    mySuit = s;
    myRank = r;
    setFace(face);
    setBack(back);

    this.setSize(face.getIconWidth(), face.getIconHeight());
    showBack();
}

public ImageIcon getFaceImage() {
    return myFace;
}

public boolean isFaceUp() {
    return true;//isFaceUp
}

public boolean isFaceDown() {
    return false;//
}

public ImageIcon getBackImage() {
    return myBack;
}

public void setFace(ImageIcon image) {
    image = myFace;
}

public void setBack(ImageIcon image) {
    image = myBack;
}

public void showBack() {
    setIcon(myBack);
    myFaceUp = false;
}

public void showFace() {
    setIcon(myFace);
    myFaceUp = true;
}

public void turnOver() {
    if(isFaceUp()) {
        showBack();
    }
    else {
        showFace();
    }
}

public int compareTo (JCardButton other) {
    if(this.getSuit().compareTo(other.getSuit()) ==0) {
        return this.getRank().compareTo(other.getRank());
    }
    else {
        return this.getSuit().compareTo(other.getSuit());
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return myRank.toString() + mySuit.toString();
}
```

}

JCardDemo
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

```
public class JCardDemo extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
private    static final long serialVersionUID = 2005L;
private    Container    window;
private    JCardButton  jcbCard;

public    void init() {
    window = new DoubleBufferedPanel();
    setContentPane(window);

    createAppearance();
    createGUI();

}

public void createAppearance(){
    window.setLayout(null);
}

public void createGUI()
{
    ImageIcon front = new ImageIcon(getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/2c.gif"));
    ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon(getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/b.gif"));

    jcbCard = new JCardButton(Suit.clubs, Rank.two, front, back);
    jcbCard.setLocation(50, 50);
    jcbCard.addActionListener(this);
    window.add(jcbCard);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JCardButton)
    {
        JCardButton c = (JCardButton) e.getSource();
        c.turnOver();
    }
    repaint();
}

class DoubleBufferedPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long    serialVersionUID = 44L;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

}

Rank enum

```
public enum Rank
{
ace,
two,
three,
four,
five,
six,
seven,
eight,
nine,
ten,
jack,
queen,
king;

public String toString()
{
    switch(this)
    {
        case ace: return "A";
        case two: return "2";
        case three: return "3";
        case four: return "4";
        case five: return "5";
        case six: return "6";
        case seven: return "7";
        case eight: return "8";
        case nine: return "9";
        case ten: return "T";
        case jack: return "J";
        case queen: return "Q";
        case king: return "K";
        default: return "??";
    }
}
```

}

Suit enum

```
public enum Suit
{
clubs, hearts, spades, diamonds;

public String toString()
{
    return this.name().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 reasons why the image switch functionality is not working here.

The first is that the image assignment is the wrong way round in `JCardButton`

```
public void setFace(ImageIcon image) {
   image = myFace; // local variable image assigned to myFace still null
}
```

it should be

```
public void setFace(ImageIcon image) {
   myFace = image;
}
```

This applys to `setBack` also.

Secondly, `isFaceUp` always returns true

```
public boolean isFaceUp() {
    return true; //??
}
```

Replace with

```
public boolean isFaceUp() {
    return myFaceUp;
}
```